# Dreamweaver 2021 - возможно ли запоминание в функции Replace (замена текста)? В Visual Studio Code, это окошко сохраняется

Tags: dreamweaver

В Visual Studio Code, это окошко сохраняется(набранный текст\код в нём) при переходе на другой файл(вкладку). А в Dreamweaver 2021, когда редактируешь 50-100 файлов очень не удобно, каждый раз набирать текст\код вновь.
Есть ли где в настройках настроить это?